# How To Save Data in CakePHP 2 for 3 tree like connected tables

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-2.0

I have 3 tree like connected tables. Their schemas as follows:

```
Member{
//Some column
}

Transactions{
member_id :: foreign key of member table
//Some other column
}

TransactionItems{
transaction_id :: foreign key of Transaction table
//Some other column
}
```

I define models like this:

```
class Members extends AppModel {

    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $hasOne = array(
        'Transactions' => array(
            'className' => 'Transactions',
            'foreignKey' => 'member_id',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );

}


class Transactions extends AppModel {

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $belongTo = array('Members');

    public $hasOne = array(
        'TransactionItems' => array(
            'className' => 'TransactionItems',
            'foreignKey' => 'transaction_id',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}


class TransactionItems extends AppModel {

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $belongTo = array('Transactions');

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Transactions' => array(
            'className' => 'Transactions',
            'foreignKey' => 'transaction_id'
        )
    );


}
```

I have a Data Array which I want to save into database. My scheme is:

```
Array(

[Members] = [],//Array
[Transactions] = [],//Array
[TransactionItems] = []//Array

)
```

The problem is that whenever I run `$this->Members->saveAll($data)`. It save data in Member and Transactions table. But do not create data in TransactionItems table. I want to save in all 3 tables at a time.

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second level (and above) associations must be nested, ie the data structure needs to be:

```
array(
    'Members' => array(),
    'Transactions' => array(
        'TransactionItems' => array()
    )
)
```

A bit awkward, but that's how it works in 2.x. You can always refer to the structure that is being returned when reading data, it needs to be the same when saving it.

Furthermore you must set the `deep` option to `true` in order to be able to save second level and above associations (by default only first level associations are being saved):

```
$this->Members->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Saving Your Data > Model::saveAssociated()](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array)**